# How can I export single value out of pandas ataframe using where function?

Tags: python, pandas, output, where-clause

my pandas dataframe is like this:

```
          a        b                         c
0         10       hi                       sth
1         300      hello                    0
2         2157     bye                      any
```

my query is like:

```
df[a].where(df['b'] == 'hi')
```

the result shows all the column a with the value for where b condition is true.
My question is how can I have a single value (as for my case only one row is true) as the result istead of a list, Which in my example is "10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
df.loc[df['b'].eq('hi'), 'a'].squeeze()
```

output: `10`

Note that in case you have more than one match, you will get a Series as output.

Comment: Alternatively, to have access to the regular expression with support of the local variables, this code is useful:
list(df[df["b"].str.contains(fr'\b{element}\b', regex=True, case=False)].a )[0])